# Complex layout in datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm trying to accomplish something like this:
[image: sample list]

Is this possible with datagridview? or ListView, or any other component in windows forms?
Notice the paddings and (most important) labels on top of each other.

How can I accomplish this in C# .NET?

Comment: WPF perhaps .. have you looked at `WPF` and custom `Stack Panels` perhaps..? if this is a web app you could create your own Control or perhaps a Repeater that embeds your custom user control you could create 2 panels with the buttons and Image component and text..etc.. what have you tried is basically what I am getting at

Comment: It is a windows forms app. Does your comment still aplly? 
I have tried "standard" listview and datagridview, but I can't solve the problem of components on top of each other within the same row

Comment: yes you can still create a `UserControl` `SoMoS` has a great suggestion as well in his answer

Comment: @SoMoS answer was right on, just wanted to add that this is how I have binded my `IList<SomeObject>` to the controls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15370914/binding-a-list-to-repeater-in-winform-application/15391306#15391306

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create a `UserControl` for each item and then you can use a [DataRepeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.datarepeater.aspx) or a [FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx).

I did things like this in the past with WinForms, so you can be sure that it's doable. Looks like WPF has erased all my previous knowledge on WinForms, kindof a virus :)

Comment: +1 I didn't know about DataRepeater. I'll try it and I'll report how it goes.

Comment: Would you kindly help me bind a IList<SomeObject> to the repeater... I can't find a way to do it (I've been able to see some examples but they all are for [ASP], not [winforms])

Comment: Here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488274.aspx it's explained how to bound the DataRepeater to a source (like your IList). Or you can always add manually the items of the IList to the control calling AddNew().