# Binding a List to Repeater in WinForm application

Tags: c#, winforms, list, binding, repeater

I recently [started this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367122/complex-layout-in-datagridview). The suggested approach was to use a `DataRepeater`.

I've seen a lot of examples on how to bind the repeater, but all of them were for ASP, not Windows Form applications.

I have added `Label`, `PictureBox` and `Button` components to the template, but I've not been able to successfully bind my `IList<SomeObject>` to my `DataRepeater`.

I'd like to populate those components with information from a list.

How to bind a `IList<SomeObject>` to a `DatarRepeater` in WinForm applications?

Comment: Are there only strings in someObject? IF so you could bind your list like this
DataRepeater.DataSource = list.Select(x=>new {Value = x}).ToList();

Comment: No, there are custom types as well. And I wish to bind some fields, not all of them. For isntance, 
`var obj = new SomeObject(); `
`obj.Name` goes to a Label, `obj.Image` goes to PictureBox, etc.

Any ideas about how is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it working! For future reference, this is what I used:

First call this method to initilize manual binding, using a `BindingSource`:

```
private BindingSource bindingSource ;
private void InitUserListArea()
{
    _bindingSource = new BindingSource();
    _bindingSource.DataSource = tempUsers;
    _labelUserListRoleValue.DataBindings.Add("Text", _bindingSource, "Role");
    _labelUserListNameValue.DataBindings.Add("Text", _bindingSource, "Name");
    _labelUserListLastAccessValue.DataBindings.Add("Text", _bindingSource, "LastAccess");
    _dataRepeaterUserList.DataSource = _bindingSource;
}
```

Then get data (in my case from a webservice) and fill the list with data. After the list is populated, or when any changes occurr:

```
private void RefreshDataRepeater()
{
    if (_dataRepeaterUserList.InvokeRequired)
    {
        _dataRepeaterUserList.Invoke((Action)(() => { RefreshDataRepeater(); }));
        return;
    }

    _bindingSource.DataSource = null;
    _bindingSource.DataSource = tempUsers;
    _dataRepeaterUserList.DataSource = null;
    _dataRepeaterUserList.DataSource = _bindingSource;
    _dataRepeaterUserList.Refresh();
}
```